# Cutting the top part of an image with overflow or clip

Tags: html, css

I am trying to cut the top part of an image using css. But using `overflow:hidden` it automatically starts hiding it from the bottom to top, while I want to keep the bottom part but cut off the top. I see there are only `x` and `y` options for overflow.

So I tried it using `clip`, but this can only be applied when the position is set to absolute or fixed, which breaks my responsiveness (and site overall).

This is how one image looks:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/eb965662ca8fabb1de523e61c16cfe83.png]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/96b5818662a8503c154524b209d88572.png]

This is my html markup of one product tile:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-80 mb-xs-40">
  <div class="post-prev-img">
    <a href="listing/product"><img src="cms/images/website/producten/categorien/product.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-prev-title font-alt align-center">
    <a href="listing/product">product</a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-prev-text align-center"></div>
  <div class="post-prev-more align-center">
    <a href="listing/product" class="btn btn-mod btn-gray btn-round"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Bekijk categorie</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I am not looking for big javascript methods, it would be great if this could be done with a couple of lines of css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.post-prev-imgbefore img  {
  border: solid 1px red; /* TO SEE RESULT... */
}

.post-prev-img {
   overflow: hidden; 
  }
.post-prev-img img  {
  border: solid 1px red; /* TO SEE RESULT... */
}
.post-prev-img a {
  height: 120px;  /* Your height... */
  position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  }

.post-prev-img a img  {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>BEFORE:</h1>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-80 mb-xs-40">
    <div class="post-prev-imgbefore">
        <a href="listing/product"><img src="https://embed.gyazo.com/eb965662ca8fabb1de523e61c16cfe83.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-prev-title font-alt align-center">
        <a href="listing/product">product</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-prev-text align-center"></div>
    <div class="post-prev-more align-center">
        <a href="listing/product" class="btn btn-mod btn-gray btn-round"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Bekijk categorie</a>
    </div>
</div>
<h1>AFTER:</h1>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-80 mb-xs-40">
    <div class="post-prev-img">
        <a href="listing/product"><img src="https://embed.gyazo.com/eb965662ca8fabb1de523e61c16cfe83.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-prev-title font-alt align-center">
        <a href="listing/product">product</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-prev-text align-center"></div>
    <div class="post-prev-more align-center">
        <a href="listing/product" class="btn btn-mod btn-gray btn-round"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Bekijk categorie</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the job.

Answer (score 2):

you can still use `overflow: hidden` , make the image, `position: absolute` and set `bottom: 0`, this way the top will overflow but will be hidden. remember for `absolute` the parent should be `position: relative`. 
so

```
.image_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  bottom: 0;
  positon: relative
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try another approach

Firstly you set a div with a defined measures and a

```
.myDiv{
 width:50%;
 height:300px;
 background-image:url('url_here');
}
```

And this way you can play with the background properties as `background-size`. I am not sure if this could solve your problem but in my opinion is the easiest way to work with images.

Answer (score -1):

What about `transform` the image inside the `overflow:hidden`-container, bro/sis? :)

```
.post-prev-img {
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post-prev-img img {
    transform: translateY(-40px)
}
```

[Bootply-link (you should use that, too)](http://www.bootply.com/lK5ExTtonx)